# trigger a function of a Arduino Uno from signal received by LoRa module

Tags: arduino-uno

I have two sx1278 Lora transceivers where both are connected to two Arduino Uno boards. I want to trigger a function in the Arduino Uno board where receiver side of LoRa connected using the signal received by Lora receiver.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Have you looked at the examples of whatever LoRa library you’re using?

Comment: "LoRa by sandeepmistry" is the library I am using. I was able to send hello packets between two LoRa modules. Now what I want is trigger a function of receiver side of Arduino from a message get from LoRa module

Comment: what is preventing you from doing that? ... you still have not asked a question

Comment: I suggest writing code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have read the datasheet for the SX1278.  If not, please refer to it at:

[SX1278 Datasheet](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/2R0000001Rc1/QnUuV9TviODKUgt_rpBlPz.EZA_PNK7Rpi8HA5..Sbo)

On page 69 you will see a couple of tables regarding the functions possible on the digital I/O (i.e. DIO) pins:

[image: SX1278 DIO Pin Functions]

I'm not clear what exactly you are looking for or which mode you are operating in (you have provided almost no information about your project) but all the information you might need is available on these DIO pins.

You can connect the appropriate pin or pins to some of the edge sensitive lines on your Arduino and define and enable an INTERRUPT in your code.  So when the event you are waiting for happens, an interrupt will occur, you can go and read the data and do whatever with it.